# React Swiper custom pagination with numbers

Tags: swiper.js, react-swiper

I'm trying to integrate a custom pagination component with Swiper with no success.

The custom pagination component renders a prev and a next button with also the number of the current slide and the total number of pages:

```js
type ArrowPaginationProps = {
  current: number;
  total: number;
  onClickPrev: () => void;
  onClickNext: () => void;
};

export const ArrowPagination = (props: ArrowPaginationProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="arrow-pagination">
      <button type="button" onClick={props.onClickPrev}>
        Prev
      </button>
      <div className="arrow-pagination-label">
        {props.current} / {props.total}
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={props.onClickNext}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And this what I've done to integrate it with swiper:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide, SwiperClass } from "swiper/react";
import { Controller } from "swiper/modules";
import { ArrowPagination } from "./ArrowPagination";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [controlledSwiper, setControlledSwiper] = useState<SwiperClass>(null);

  const handleClickPrev = () => controlledSwiper.slidePrev();
  const handleClickNext = () => controlledSwiper.slideNext();

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        modules={[Controller]}
        controller={{ control: controlledSwiper }}
        onSwiper={setControlledSwiper}
      >
        {slides.map((text, idx) => {
          return <SwiperSlide key={idx}>{text}</SwiperSlide>;
        })}
        <div slot="container-end">
          <ArrowPagination
            current={controlledSwiper?.activeIndex + 1}
            total={slides.length}
            onClickPrev={handleClickPrev}
            onClickNext={handleClickNext}
          />
        </div>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}

const slides = [
  "Slide 1",
  "Slide 2",
  "Slide 3",
  "Slide 4",
  "Slide 5",
  "Slide 6",
  "Slide 7",
  "Slide 8",
  "Slide 9",
  "Slide 10",
];
```

The issue is that, when I click the prev or next button, the `current` page number is not being updated.

Reproducible sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-swipper-custom-pagination-hq73hw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide, SwiperClass } from "swiper/react";
import { Controller } from "swiper/modules";
import { ArrowPagination } from "./ArrowPagination";
import "swiper/css";
import "./styles.css";
    
export default function App() {
  const [controlledSwiper, setControlledSwiper] = useState<SwiperClass>(null);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
    
  const handleClickPrev = () => controlledSwiper.slidePrev();
  const handleClickNext = () => controlledSwiper.slideNext();
    
  const handleSlideChange = () => {
    setActiveIndex(controlledSwiper?.activeIndex || 0);
  };
    
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        modules={[Controller]}
        controller={{ control: controlledSwiper }}
        onSwiper={setControlledSwiper}
        onSlideChange={handleSlideChange}
      >
        {slides.map((text, idx) => {
          return <SwiperSlide key={idx}>{text}</SwiperSlide>;
        })}
      </Swiper>
      <ArrowPagination
        current={activeIndex + 1}
        total={slides.length}
        onClickPrev={handleClickPrev}
        onClickNext={handleClickNext}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-swipper-custom-pagination-forked-vp7l7f?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx

Comment: Actually, this is the approach that I ended up using. 